# IF condition in repeater - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to use if condition inside repeater control on asp.net webform?

I need to show PercentEngineeringDesign field value if ScopeTypeID = 2 otherwise show empty field.

I am getting error on true part (second parameter).

```
 <td><%# If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScopeTypeID").ToString() = "2", <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PercentEngineeringDesign")%>, "")%>   </td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the markup.  You should be performing this check in the code behind and storing the already-derived result in the datasource so that the markup only needs to bind to the resulting property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can cent the `<%` tags like that.  Try just:

```
<td><%# If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScopeTypeID").ToString() = "2", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PercentEngineeringDesign"), "")%>   </td>
```

Or better yet, do that logic in your *model* instead of in the *markup*.

Answer (score 0):

you can create other property in your class and do all work there then just display result in repeater
just like  this:

```
public int ID { get;set;};
public int Code {get  { // Do Your if condition here }}
```

then display code as `statue of ID`